# WordPress fails to connect to MySQL but Workbench will

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

So my problem is that we are trying to set up a WordPress site on a Windows server (2012) under IIS. I used WebPI to install PHP and used the PHP Manager to configure it. We have a database server at 10.0.0.x which runs both SQL Server and MySQL. We got it all set up, but WordPress doesn't connect. We get the following error:

> Access denied for user 'user'@'ip-10-0-0-x.x.compute.internal' (using password: YES)

I have tried this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
```

I also tried that with the `mysql_connect` extension with the same results. So then I tried this:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=10.0.0.x;dbname=DB_NAME', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS');
$statement = $pdo->query("SELECT user_login FROM wp_users WHERE ID = 1");
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo htmlentities($row['user_login']);
```

And that worked perfectly. It connected, ran the query, and returned the value. MySQL Workbench was also able to connect. I was able to determine that WordPress is using `mysqli` with a fallback to the `mysql` library. And that's probably why it's failing to connect. But what's the difference and why would it authenticate one but not the other?

MySQL Community version: 5.6

PHP 5.3 (initially tried 5.6)

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Because the question came up, I realize WordPress works. That's not the question. The MySQL user is set up as 'user'@'%'. Obviously I can connect to that user on that server from that host, using PDO. My question is why can PDO connect while mysqli cannot?

Answer (score -2):

Well, you know, WordPress works properly.  It has tens of millions of working installations. It works on every configuration we can imagine and some we can't. Mucking around with php versions and all that is probably a waste of time.

Take a look at the `wp-config.php` file in your WordPress installation's root directory on your server.  Look for these lines:

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'REDACTED_DATABASE_NAME');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'REDACTED_USER_NAME');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'REDACTED_PASSWORD');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'your_host_name_or_ip_address');
```

Make sure these values are what you think they should be. If the values are incorrect, edit them.

Keep in mind that MySQL needs separate user accounts for user@localhost and user@anotherhost.

Comment: I know WordPress works correctly. My thinking is that there's something messed up with my PHP installation or some version incompatibility that I'm unaware of. I copied the user/name/password directly from the `wp-config.php` and have used them in Workbench just fine. The user is actually 'user'@'%' with firewall rules in place.